# Subset size of Baggingclassifier in sklearn

Tags: scikit-learn, ensemble-learning

If I understand it correctly, bagging is supposed to do the prediction based on average (or the most probable) result of multiple models created on random subsets of the training data set. However, in the BaggingClassifier (http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.ensemble.BaggingClassifier.html) of scikit-learn, there seems to be no way to set the size of the random subset.

How does the package determine the size of each random subset?

Comment: Isn't it? `max_samples - The number of samples to draw from X to train each base estimator.`

Comment: @ Thanks, just figured it out.